# Книги по Delphi

Tags: delphi, книги

Можете посоветовать хорошие, книги по Delphi для продвинутых пользователей?

Работаю с Delphi. Порой базовых знаний не хватает для реализации каких-то идей.  Нужны книги в которых не описывается создание новой формы и размещение кнопок на ней, а которые предполагают углубленное изучение среды - различные нестандартные решения проблем, ООП, WinApi, работа с динамическими библиотеками, потоки, математические задачи и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грешным делом в голову пришел Флёнов с его `%что-нибудь% глазами хакера` )

По Delphi литературы уровня Фаулера и Блоха я что-то не встречал. Но много интересных решений можно почерпнуть из широкоизвестных источников:

- [К О Р О Л Е В С Т В О Делфи](http://delphikingdom.ru/)
- Сборник рецептов известный как kuliba.chm (загуглите)

Вообще, (не холивора ради) с точки зрения зрелости платформы, развитости сообщества и экосистемы Delphi не дотягивает до уровня многих других популярных языков (может быть когда-нибудь, но пока перспективы сомнительны). Поэтому и нет достойной литературы, нет евангелистов, а язык продолжает восприниматься как VisualBasic с синтаксисом Паскаля.

Есть интересные блоггеры, которые стараются своими статьями и переводами восполнить этот пробел:

- [TDelphi: будни Delphi блоггера](http://www.tdelphiblog.com/)
- GunSmoker: [блог](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/) и [переводы](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/)

Могу также порекомендовать изучать классическую литературу по разработке ПО ([Макконнелл](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3159814/), [GoF](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/), [Джоэл Спольски](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2820575/), [Рихтер](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4079733/) и т.п., упоминались тут не раз), лучше в оригинале, и проецировать полученные знания на Delphi.

Comment: вот еще интересный ресурс http://www.webdelphi.ru/

Comment: @teanЫЧ?, cпасибо, видел. Но не впечатлился, поэтому сюда добавлять не стал. Как-то очень напоминает стародавние статьи из журнала  на букву `][`: "Пишем свой IRC-клиент: скачиваем компонент, кидаем на форму, вводим адрес сервера, получаем по событию сообщения, ура работает! Ты круто постарался!".

 А вы просили про  "углубленное изучение среды".

Comment: понимаю. меня, в общем, этот ресурс заинтересовал только тем, что автор подробно разбирает FireMonkey.

Answer (score 3):

**"Библия Делфи" отличная книга как для профессионалов так и для начинающих!**

**[Этот](http://www.delphiworld.narod.ru/)** сайт, один из немногих с огромными запасами кода, статей + программа по этим статьям там прилагается. Я в своё время штудировал этот сайт. Очень помогал в программировании